# Write.table gives weird output when character variable contains "\n"

Tags: r, export, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, write.table

I have a large survey data set which contains numericals and free text variables (comments). I imported the data.set in R and did some editing and wanted to share the cleaned dataset with my collaboraters. I used write.table to create a csv. file. When importing this file in Excel 2013 I realized that the data had 91 additional rows compared to the data.frame in R. The reason for the additional line seem to be "\n" included in free texts by participants. The data looks like the following:

```
test = data.frame (Int = seq(1,100, 1),
               Text=rep(c("^^v"),100),
               Fail = c(rep(c("Yes"),50),c("test \n"),rep(c("Yes"),49)) )
test$Fail = as.character(test$Fail)
```

The test data.frame has 100 observations of three variables. When I now save the data.frame using write.table like:

```
write.table(test, "test.csv", sep = ",", dec = ".", col.names = FALSE)
```

and import the test.csv in Excel it has 101 data rows including an empty row after "test \n". I know that \n indicates a new line. How can I handle this as several participants entered free text including \n. I do not want to manually delete all those cases. Does anyone has an idea how I can make R write.table to output the correct data.frame?

Comment: Is it ok to remove that portion of the variable prior to writing the file: `test$Fail <- gsub("\\n","",test$Fail )`

Comment: Wow, that was quick! gsub() seems to perfectly do the job! I just replaced the \n with ";" to not loose the information about linebreaks. Why did you use a double slash \\ before the n? It works perfectly for my example and also within my dataset! Thank you very much for the super quick help!

Comment: Well, the slash is itselt an escape character, so gsub needs to escape the escape operator so the \n in the text gets treated as text not as the new line.